# Defuse the bomb, Mr. Rossi!

Tags: calculation-puzzle, password

This is a very hot summer in Rome and you don't know what to do. You are the best detective in town but no crime seems to happen. You are all the day in front of your PC trying to solve some puzzles about parties and elephants but you can't find any solution so far. You are on the way to solving the 20th when a young policeman rushes into your room and gives you a letter. 
"Get the hell out! I had the solution of that devilish puzzle and now it is gone! Get out!"
He can't understand your frustration and closes the door as fast as he could. 
Anyway, you opened up the letter and started to read:

```
Rome, 22/7/14
AHAHA Mr. Rossi, I have planted a bomb into the Colosseum! It will explode tonight at 24:00. 
I know you are a puzzle-lover, so I would give you a chance to defuse it. Go there and
and follow the instructions, every clue is important, so be focused! 
You will find a 6-fold piece of paper with some hints to crack the bomb!
Good Luck!
The evil bomber
```

"Accipicchia [Oh my gosh]" you said "I need to move!" 
You started to run to the Colosseum and after 20 minutes you found the bomb and the instruction. There is a keyboard and a monitor linked to the bomb. On the screen, you can see a textbox which allows you to type in just 4 characters and big red text saying: "Enter the password".
You opened up the piece of paper and started to read the hint.

```
Let's do some math: 
2^2 = ...
3^2 = ... 
5^2 = ...
7^2 = ...
11^2 = ...
You can choose to stop here or keep on with all the prime numbers you can evaluate!
Now you should know the password!
The evil bomber
```

You started to think about for a while and after 20 minutes you started to type the solution that came up in your mind. After you pressed enter, on the screen you saw **"The bomb has been defused!"**
"Perbacco [My goodnees], I made it! Now I need to find the solution of the 20th party!".

**The puzzle:**
What is the password and how did he come up with that?

**Edit:**
Let's add some hints to help you to find the right solution.

**Hint #1**

> The evil bomber is a PhD in Math, but he did not find any job and he started his career as a terrorist. Loving numbers, every number he gave are there for a reason, but one, just to make him struggle a little more.

**Hint #2**

> Mr. Rossi is a fan of Math History, he loves [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) too. He found in a while which "subject" of the hints the evil bomber gave to him. It was easy, every numbers are linked univocally to that subject. It was easy to type the right answer this way.

**Hint #3**

> During his PhD, the evil bomber studied a lot [Euler](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerProduct.html), Reimann, and their [Euler-Reimann Z function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) He found with joy they are related to [PI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Number_theory_and_Riemann_zeta_function).

**Reference**

> You can find at [prodotto di Eulero](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_greco#Analisi) the relation between primes and $\pi$. If you want more, you can see this [one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Number_theory_and_Riemann_zeta_function) and read the demostration [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerProduct.html)

Anyway guys, I actually hope you had fun with this riddle as I had!

Comment: Does '6-fold piece of paper' mean 'piece of paper folded 6 times'?

Comment: @AE Yes, If you feel like it's not clear, I'll try to rearrange it!

Comment: No need, with that little clarification it's quite clear.

Comment: Sorry, bad time at work! I will give hints tonight when I come back home! Anyway, you are a bit far from solution!

Comment: +1 for a great question and the HSM mention. Nobody's posted the fully right answer yet?

Comment: @HDE226868 Not yet!

Comment: +1 for mentioning one of the party series questions which I created.

Comment: "The evil bomber is a PhD in Math, but he did not find any job and he started his career as a terrorist." He obviously wasn't paying attention when the joke was told, "What is the difference between a Math PhD and a large pizza? The large pizza can feed a family of four!"

Comment: +1 since I'm doing a maths PhD and studying the zeta function :-) Could the answer be ZETA? Or, since you said every number is relevant (including how many times the paper is folded), does it relate to zeta(6)=(pi^6)/945 ?

Comment: @randal'thor You are the closest right now! Nice try but not the answer I'm looking for! But you are on the right track!

Comment: Do you have to enter EXACTLY four characters, or is it just at most four (so the answer could be 'pi')?

Comment: @randal'thor Exactly 4

Comment: The greatest detective can think about the password in 20 minutes which the entire stack community can't and he can't even think about the password to the 20th party??? Are you kidding me?!?!??

Comment: @AE (or whoever awards the bounty, if it doesn't have to be the offerer) - can I split the bounty with nexolute?

Comment: @randal'thor, I can't award the bounty for another 15 hours, when I can I'll give it to you, then you can award half of it as a bounty to nexolute for their answer if you want. I think the system allows that.

Comment: oh noes! catastrophic proof-reading error! Never mind, you'll just have to do another one. ;)

Comment: Just did the record, hour 24:00 doesn't exist, it's really 0:00

Comment: Is it me or is the solution a bit of a stretch? May be for non math students it looks very simply: keep squaring primes until you get the first four digit number, that occurs at 37 (a prime, right? ) so is it possible?

Comment: seeing so many different answers, i think safest thing is call bomb squad and let professionals to handle bomb

Comment: @user902383 - The main reason there are so many different answers is that the OP made a mistake in the question originally. As it stands, the question is easy to answer for anyone with a degree in maths (the bomber has, and maybe Mr Rossi too?)

Comment: There is a blatant flaw here which I can't believe nobody has noticed. The sum 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + 1/5^2 + 1/7^2 + ... is not equal to pi^2/6. If you wanted to get pi^2/6 you would just take the sum of the reciprocals of the squares of all the integers, not just the primes. That is, pi^2/6 = 1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + 1/4^2 + ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess, motivated by @nexolute 's answer:

> $\pi^2/6$

(assuming the 'characters' you can input don't have to be letters or numbers). Reasoning:

> As many people have already noticed, $\pi$ is important somehow. The Riemann zeta function was mentioned in the third hint, and $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ is its best-known value. The number 6 is suggested by the six-fold piece of paper. And the sum of the reciprocals of all squares of primes is $\pi^2/6$.

(In the OP's original question, the numbers on the bomber's last note were (prime)^(prime) instead of (prime)^2; this is why the question generated answers such as 5^5 and took such a long time to solve. But the OP only spotted his error after the solution had already been found!)

Comment: We have a winner! $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ can be evalued as a sum of the reciprocal of prime numbers squared.

Comment: @Emi987 - Yes, I know, but what does that have to do with raising a prime to the power of itself?

Comment: Because I'm derp. Never spotted that horrid mistake since now.. Editing. Feeling so sorry.. :(

Comment: If I'd seen the question as it stands now, I would've got the answer (almost) immediately!

Comment: @Emi987: oops! :)

Comment: @randal'thor Congrats and thanks. Haha, I really did wrote the exact answer in my "answer". Seems like I just cannot get over with the prime^prime clue. Now it's clarified to be squared, I think I can rest in peace.

Answer (score 10):

Here are my thoughts:

> 4 Characters, not 4 Numbers, so the password is:
>  22/7
>  It's the historical approximation of pi, and the date of the letter.
>  Bonus: the prime counting function is denoted as pi(x)

Comment: +1 because you're so right! Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: You are on the right track my man! You are one step away from the solution!

Comment: @Emi987 I'm not following how this is related to n^n where n is prime...

Comment: @Micheal There is one and only one. I'll give an hint soon!

Comment: @Michael: well that series is also called pi (no relation), but I'm not sure where that info takes us.

Answer (score 7):

> Everything is related to $\pi$.
>  -22/7 is approximation of $\pi$ (tempted to think that it will be $\pi/14$, but $14$ is probably useless).
>  -<s>24:00, which can also be written as $4\pi$ in radian (that's why you didnt write 00:00).</s>
>  - 6-folded paper, which appears in $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ (makes me wonder if paper's length is $\pi$).
>  - Primes are related to $\pi$ in many ways (not sure why powered to itself though).

That said, I still don't have a solution. Derp.

Comment: How is 24:00 the same as 2pi??

Comment: You indirectly wrote the solution, my friend. Don't be a derp, keep on going! **Ps:** 24.00 is just a stupind number not related to the solution btw :P

Comment: @randal'thor, my bad. Seems like 24 hours will require the hour hand to spin around the clock twice, which will be 4π.

Comment: @Emi987. Am I right to say that "You can choose to stop here or keep on with all the prime numbers you can evaluate!" means that you are computing an infinite series that will approximate the answer, but computing up to the fifth term is good enough for the 4 characters solution? In that case, maybe we can compute pi^2/6 and get **1.64**. But it still doesn't justify why prime^prime, hmmm...

Comment: @nexolute You are absolute right, but you are keeping on going around the answer without spotting it. You got it, actually, but it's still not what I'm looking for! It's easier than the evaluation, trust me! I can tell you you spotted all the clues!

Comment: I'm confused. Did I literally wrote the solution in some form, or are there still deductions to be made?

Comment: @Emi987 - Is the solution 'pi/14', either with 'pi' as one character or excluding the '/'? Maybe this is the sum of the reciprocals of p^p for primes p or something?

Comment: @nexolute Something does contain the solution!

Comment: @randal'thor Close one!

Comment: Could it be 22/2, by taking (22/7)/14.

Comment: @nexolute - I got the right answer, inspired by your answer; I'm trying to find out if we can split the bounty between us :-)

Comment: @nexolute - AE says I can award half of the bounty to you after he awards it to me, some time tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

My attempt is

> 3125

The reasoning:

> Of the calculations listed, 5^5 is the only one that has an answer 4 digits long.

Answer (score 6):

**It didn't matter what you type. The bomb won't go off anyway**

> 24 Hour clocks run from 00:00.00 to 23:59.59 and then roll back over to 00:00.00. If the bomber has set the clock to detonate at **24:00** then the clock will never reach that number.

Comment: The note doesn't say "I set the timer to 24:00", but "it will explode at 24:00", which is fine used in speech/writing [where convenient.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00)

Answer (score 5):

> did anyone notice the date of the message wrote at 22/7? and it will blow up at midnight, which will change the time to 23/7 00:00. since the topic is prime number, 23 and 7 are prime number too. 
>  so i think that the answer is 23/7

Answer (score 4):

I'm just going to try..

> NONE, since anything raised to a number except 0 or 1 have multiples and cant be a prime number

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @AE I guees I'm wrong on understanding the question XD

Answer (score 4):

Is the solution 1.006. Calculated as ζ(2), where we calculate for the next prime that is 13.

Answer (score 2):

> The answer is 3125
>  5^5 is the only such equation with an answer of 4 digits.
>
>  4^4 = 256
>  5^5 = 3125
>  6^6 = 46656

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is

> 0169

Since the paper was folded 6 times, that probably means that the password is

> the square of the sixth prime

However, it took me around 20 seconds to get this answer, not 20 minutes, so perhaps this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Puzzle seems to say x^x, not x^2.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> zero, because that's what the reimann zeta function tends to, or zeros are kind of important in the study of it or something?

?

(no maths phd here, can you tell?)

or just

> zeta

maybe?

Comment: I guessed 'zeta' too, but that was wrong. The most famous open problem on the zeta function involves its zeros, but that seems a bit too far-fetched for this problem (and doesn't have anything to do with pi).